# action web service in rails 3.0.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new in rails i want to communicate two rails application from them one in rails 1.2.3 and another is in rails 3.0.5 by using web_service .
So please help me how to generate web_service in rails 3.0.5 .

Answer (score 0):

`action_web_service` was deprecated for a very good reason: it was terrible.

I would recommend generating an JSON API on the applications that need to communicate to each other.